# How to remove the bootloader unlocked sign while restarting device

Tags: root-access, nexus-6p

Ever since I unlocked my Nexus 6p to root the device, I started getting the boot-loader unlocked sign with a big flashing yellow icon telling me to go to some link to reset my device. It is quite annoying when this happens. Is there a way to remove this icon without re-locking the device?

Android: 7.1.1 Nougat (rooted w/ TWRP)

[image: Bootloader Issue]

Comment: There is no way to remove this warning. The only way is locking the bootloader.

Comment: I believe nothing is impossible, whatever the cost

Comment: The warning is a part of [boot verify](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/verified-boot.html) process - see Fig 1.This [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/3phaw6/nexus_6p_has_a_hardware_fuse_that_blows/) explains that it is a hardware fuse, which **cannot be undone** by locking the bootloader. So i guess there is no way

Answer (score 1):

Someone found a way to get rid of this screen on a Nexus 5X by replacing the imgdata bitmap files. Not sure if there is a one for 6P.

[XDA forum link here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-5x/themes-apps/tool-change-bootlogo-images-imgdata-tool-t3240052)